# UserControl Close Trigger don't Fire

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, user-controls

For this problem, let me explain the environment.

I have a UserControl in XAML, I can't reach the code behind, I've to do all in the XAML part. I don't have any access to the Window code also. Only the usercontrolwho have to save the window position.

The problem is : my close trigger never fired (but this trigger work fine with a Cancel button click further in the code)

I can't reach the only part of code I've access to. 
I can't put the trigger before the resources, because of the userCommandBuilder.

The trigger.

```
<UserControl     
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
...otherstuff...
MinWidth="946" MinHeight="902" MaxWidth="946" MaxHeight="902">
  <UserControl.Resources.../>
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Close">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Static addin:AddInCommands.ExecuteCmdLine}" >
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource userCommandBuilder}" ConverterParameter="SRSAVEPOSITION -T {0} -L {1}">
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="Top"  />
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="Left"  />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
            </i:InvokeCommandAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

What did I wrong ? 
How to solve that ?

Cancel button code

```
<Button Margin="0,0,0,0" IsCancel="True"  FontSize="13" FontFamily="Segoe UI">Cancel>
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Static addin:AddInCommands.ExecuteCmdLine}" >
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource userCommandBuilder}" ConverterParameter="SRSAVEPOSITION -T {0} -L {1}">
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="Top"  />
                                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="Left"  />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="ApplicationCommands.Close" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

Comment: Have you got the code for `Cancel`? So we can compare.

Comment: Yup, I come back tommorow with the Cancel button code.

Comment: Code added. Not that different from the Close event.
but if close event or unloaded event don't exist on usercontrol, I don't see how to do that this way :)

Answer (score 1):

A `UserControl` has no `Close` event. If you want to handle the `Closing` or `Closed` event of the parent window in the `UserControl` class, you have to write some code. You cannot do this in XAML.

You could for example get a reference to the `Window` once the `UserControl` has been loaded and execute your command:

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) => 
        {
            Window window = Window.GetWindow(this);
            if(window != null)
                window.Closing += Window_Closing;
        };
    }

    private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        AddInCommands.ExecuteCmdLine.Execute(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the code behind, that's the difficult part of the job ^^
But I think we've found a solution.
Comming back soon with the answer.